# Retrieve Data from Database using Shortcode

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress, shortcode

I am trying to retrieve data from a wordpress table using a shortcode function I found. It works and retrieves the data for all the columns. When I try to specify the columns I want it still give me everything. Ultimately what I am trying to do is retrieve the data for the columns I want and style that data using css (not in a table format). I am new to php so I was wondering if anyone could let me know if this is even possible using shortcodes. If it is possible any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance, Randy

Here is the code I am using:

```
if ( !defined( 'WP_FD_ABSPATH' ) )

define( 'WP_FD_ABSPATH', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );

function wp_first_shortcode($atts){
global $wpdb;
$a = shortcode_atts( array(
'table_name' => ",
'columns' => ",
), $atts );
$showcolumns=array();
if($a['columns']!=""){
$column=$a['columns'];
$showcolumns=explode(',',$a['columns']);
}
else{
$column='*';
$get_columns=$wpdb->get_results("describe ".$a['table_name']."");
foreach($get_columns as $fields) $showcolumns[]=$fields->Field;
}

$columncount=count( $showcolumns);

$result_query=$wpdb->get_results( "select $column from ".$a['table_name']."");
echo '<table><tr>';
for($i=0;$i<$columncount;$i++) echo '<th>'.$showcolumns[$i].'</th>';
echo '</tr>';
foreach($result_query as $result_row){
echo '<tr>';
for($i=0;$i<$columncount;$i++) echo '<td>'.$result_row->$showcolumns[$i].'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
}
add_shortcode('fetchdata', 'wp_first_shortcode');
function table_value_function() {
query_value(array('orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC' , 'showvalues' => ""));
wp_reset_query();
return $return_string;
}
?>
```

Here is the shortcode I am using:

```
[fetchdata table_name='my_wp_table' columns ='Display_Name' 'First_Name' 'Last_Name' 'Address_1' 'Address_2' 'City' 'State' 'Phone']
```

Comment: What I am still trying to figure out is how to how to retrieve only the columns I want to display using this shortcode: [fetchdata table_name='my_wp_table' columns ='Display_Name' 'First_Name' 'Last_Name' 'Address_1' 'Address_2' 'City' 'State' 'Phone'] Currently I get all the values for each column in the table. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance, Randy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think you just want to get rid of the table as you want to style it with CSS. Please follow the code below:

```
echo '<div class="something">';
for($i=0;$i<$columncount;$i++) echo '<h1>'.$showcolumns[$i].'</h1>';

foreach($result_query as $result_row){
echo '<div class="something_2">';
for($i=0;$i<$columncount;$i++) echo '<p>'.$result_row->$showcolumns[$i].'</p>';
echo '</div>';
}
echo '</div>';
}
```

Hope, it helps.

Comment: Perfect! I left a positive vote but since I am a newbie it did not show. Thank you very much I removed the echo for showing the column headers since I will be applying labels. The thing that I don't get is how to retrieve only the columns I want using my shortcode: [fetchdata table_name='my_wp_table' columns ='Display_Name' 'First_Name' 'Last_Name' 'Address_1' 'Address_2' 'City' 'State' 'Phone']

Comment: You can accept the answer if it answers your question. I'll update the answer for you later.

Comment: Okay I clicked the check mark and it is now green. Thank you!

Comment: What I am still trying to figure out is how to how to retrieve only the columns I want to display using this shortcode: [fetchdata table_name='my_wp_table' columns ='Display_Name' 'First_Name' 'Last_Name' 'Address_1' 'Address_2' 'City' 'State' 'Phone'] Currently I get all the values for each column in the table. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance, Randy